# Is SQLite really cross-platform?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cross-platform

I'm using SQLite to store some data. The primary database is on a NAS (Debian Lenny, 2.6.15, armv4l) since the NAS runs a script which updates the data every day. A typical "select * from tableX" looks like this:

```
2010-12-28|20|62.09|25170.0
2010-12-28|21|49.28|23305.7
2010-12-28|22|48.51|22051.1
2010-12-28|23|47.17|21809.9
```

When I copy the DB to my main computer (Mac OS X) and run the same SQL query, the output is:

```
2010-12-28|20|1.08115035175016e-160|25170.0
2010-12-28|21|2.39343503830763e-259|-9.25596535779558e+61
2010-12-28|22|-1.02951149572792e-86|1.90359837597183e+185
2010-12-28|23|-1.10707273937033e-234|-2.35343828462275e-185
```

The 3rd and 4th column have the type REAL. Interesting fact: When the numbers are integer (i.e. they end with ".0"), there is no difference between the two databases. In all other cases, the differences are ... hm ... surprising? I can't seem to find a pattern.

If someone's got a clue - please share!

PS: sqlite3 -version output
 Debian: 3.6.21 (lenny-backports)
 Mac OS X: 3.6.12 (10.6)

Comment: I can't find a pattern either.  It's NOT byte-swapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In release [3.4.0](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_4_0) of SQLite there was a compile time flag added.

> - Added the SQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT compile-time option to support ARM7 processors with goofy endianness.

I was having this same problem with an Arm920Tid device and my x86 based VM.  The arm device was writing the data, and I was trying to read it on the x86 VM (or on my Mac).

After adding this compile time flag to my makefile for my arm build I was able to get sane values when I queried the DB on either platform.

For reference I am using sqlite 3.7.14

Answer (score 2):

It should be, the [file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) says that REAL is stored in big-endian format, which would be architecture-invariant if serialized correctly by both builds.

> A value of 7 stored within the database record header indicates that the corresponding database value is an SQL real (floating point number). In this case the blob of data contains an 8-byte IEEE floating point number, **stored in big-endian byte order**.

Comment: I'm relieved that it *should* be cross-platform but I'm wondering what is causing these differences in my sqlite db.

Comment: Probably a bug in the implementation.